# react spinner promise dosen't work correctly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, promise

i have an app that i build on react native and i have a problem with create a spinner
i have function named "calculatorLoops" this function as another function that has nasted loop and it caculation the numbers.
the problem is i want to "wait" until the loop is over and create a spinner while it make the calculation.
so i make it async and it not working.
but if i await with some fetch url it does working as well, i try to replace the await fetch with promise but it not work but only with the await fetch (and with this its working as well but i dont really need to fetch)

```
  const calculatorLoops = async (column: string) => {
    await fetch("https://www.google.com/");
    let howManyLoop = 0;
    let isWon = false;
    let founds;

    while (!isWon) {
      founds = compareNumbers(user.lotteryNumbers[column], { lotteryNumbers: createNumbers() });

      howManyLoop++;
      if (founds.cnt === loopNum) isWon = true;
    }
    setFoundNum({ foundCnt: howManyLoop, foundNumbers: founds.foundsNumbers });
  };


  const handlePress = async (column: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    await calculatorLoops(column);
    setLoading(false);
  };


//promise function

  const calculatorLoops = async (column: string) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      let howManyLoop = 0;
      let isWon = false;
      let founds;

      while (!isWon) {
        founds = compareNumbers(user.lotteryNumbers[column], { lotteryNumbers: createNumbers() });

        howManyLoop++;
        if (founds.cnt === loopNum) isWon = true;
      }
      res(setFoundNum({ foundCnt: howManyLoop, foundNumbers: founds.foundsNumbers }));
    });
  };
```

Comment: It's because your function there is no return and promise. You may add return as promise, or use the `useEffect` hook to check the `foundNum` state.

Comment: I think i didnt write it correctly.  As i show in this code its working. But , tou can see that i add await fetch to google url, and it dosent should be i only add this because on this approch the spinner work correctly. What i want to do is: get rid of the await fetch and make this as promise i will add the code that i write with the promise below